# Algolia search - Unable to reindex locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, algolia

I'm using Algolia for the first time and trying to get reindexing to work locally but it's throwing the error below:

```
Algolia::AlgoliaError: API not initialized

2016-09-30T06:18:00.071Z 50262 TID-oxqk9ev1w WARN: {"class":"Search::SomeWorker","args":[2,false],"retry":5,"queue":"default","jid":"1519b78812e13d6df5fdb6a9","created_at":1475216280.067702,"enqueued_at":1475216280.067759,**"error_message":"API not initialized","error_class":"Algolia::AlgoliaError"**,"failed_at":1475216280.0707068,"retry_count":0}
**2016-09-30T06:18:00.071Z 50262 TID-oxqk9ev1w WARN: Algolia::AlgoliaError: API not initialized**
2016-09-30T06:18:00.071Z 50262 TID-oxqk9ev1w WARN: /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-1.11.0/lib/algolia/client.rb:657:in `client'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-1.11.0/lib/algolia/index.rb:11:in `initialize'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:229:in `new'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:229:in `initialize'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:647:in `new'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:647:in `algolia_ensure_init'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:492:in `block in algolia_index!'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:489:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:489:in `algolia_index!'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@foro/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.15.0/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:792:in `algolia_index!'
```

I had no trouble connecting to the Algolia client as shown below:

```
[1] pry(main)> Algolia::Client.new(application_id: xxx, api_key: xxx)
=> #<Algolia::Client:0x007fe100329f40
 @api_key="xxx",
 @application_id="xxx",
 @batch_timeout=120,
 @connect_timeout=2,
 @headers=
  {"X-Algolia-API-Key"=>"xxx",
   "X-Algolia-Application-Id"=>"xxx",
   "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "User-Agent"=>"Algolia for Ruby 1.11.0"},
 @hosts=["xxx.algolia.net", "xxx-1.algolianet.com", "xxx-3.algolianet.com", "xxx-2.algolianet.com"],
 @receive_timeout=30,
 @search_hosts=["xxx-dsn.algolia.net", "xxx-2.algolianet.com", "xxx-1.algolianet.com", "xxx-3.algolianet.com"],
 @search_timeout=5,
 @send_timeout=30,
 @ssl=true,
 @ssl_version=nil>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While the error and the pry output is good, we need to see the minimum script that reproduces the problem. See "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you're [mixing up the 2 ways](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-ruby/blob/6ea198bf5241eb4cdf30c4d97c104f0401cac9b7/lib/algolia/client.rb#L658) to use the underlying Ruby API client. There are 2 ways to use the Algolia Ruby API client:

- with the singleton design pattern (1 global API client);
- or with regular N client instances.

Looks like here you're trying to use the **Rails** integration which assume you have initialised the underlying API client globally (using the singleton design pattern).

Using the Rails integration, rather than calling `Algolia::Client.new` you should use:

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: 'xxx', api_key: 'xxx' }
# this will call Algolia.init
```

You can find more documentation [on GitHub](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#configuration).

---

If you want to use the underlying Ruby API client, without the Rails integration; you can choose between:

Using the raw Ruby API client, the singleton way:

```
Algolia.init application_id: 'xxx', api_key: 'xxx'
index = Algolia::Index.new('myindex') # it will use the API client initialised globally
index.add_objects(...)
```

Using the raw Ruby API client, the N instances way:

```
client = Algolia::Client.new application_id: 'xxx', api_key: 'xxx'
index = client.init_index('myindex')
index.add_objects(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Redox.

That's correct - I'm trying to use the Rails integration and I did actually configure it with

`AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: 'xxx', api_key: 'xxx' }`

in the initialiser file. So I'm baffled as to why the Algolia API still failed to initialise. It's only failing locally as it initialised properly in my staging environment.

FYI - The Algolia error was noticed in the Sidekiq output.

Comment: Weird :/ Do you think your Sidekiq worker is not loading the full environment , avoiding the configuration to be set on time?

Comment: Also, did you put that `AlgoliaSearch.configuration` in the a `config/initializers/algolia.rb` file?

Comment: Redox, you're brilliant! My Sidekiq was not loading the full environment. Had to restart my terminal window and voila! Thanks for your help.

Comment: It says on github: "Create a new file config/initializers/algoliasearch.rb" i tried this and algolia.rb both names, but still i am unable to get it configured in my console.